# rosservice via Python

Tags: ros

I have a drone which has certain services, say random.srv. I want to use this service via Python. Now I know that there is a page in ROS wiki that tells you how to create a service client in Python. Unfortunately that is not sufficient for me. Here goes my case:

Once I start the drone node, the service is listed as

```
/main/random_task
```

**Now an important point to note** is that the name of the service is as stated above

```
random.srv
```

The function that I am writing is:

```
from random.srv import *
import rospy

def enableRandom():
    rospy.wait_for_service('main/random_task')
    try:
        droneRandom = rospy.ServiceProxy('main/random_task', random)
        doSomething(1)  # something seems to be missing

    except rospy.ServiceException:
        print('Service call failed')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    enableRandom()
```

The thing is it gives an error saying random is undefined. But that is the name of the srv file.

Can someone also explain why it doesn't work the way it should. You can guess by this question that I am new to this.

Edit 1:
Now I understand that in the statement

```
from random.srv import *
```

the 'random' should be the package name. This is not the case. The package name is, lets call it **my-package1**. The service **random.srv** that I want to use is in

```
src/my-package1/main/srv/
```

Another thing to clear up is that **/main/random_task** is the name with which **random.srv** is shown in **rosservice list**. The new code now is

```
from my-package1.srv import random
import rospy

def enableRandom():
    rospy.wait_for_service('/main/random_task')
    try:
        droneRandom = rospy.ServiceProxy('/main/random_task', random)
        doSomething()

    except rospy.ServiceException:
        print('Service call failed')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    enableRandom()
```

Now I get **my-project1** as having invalid syntax (I guess due to having '-'symbol). If I use

```
from main.srv import random
```

it says it cannot find **'main'**.

First if I have to use **'my-project1.srv'** how to I get around the syntax issue with '-'.

Secondly, if I have to use the subfolder name i.e. **main.srv**, why does it not recognize the package if it can recognize the services inside it (when using rosservice list on the terminal).

I think there is an issue with the syntax.

Comment: Do you still have a question?

Comment: @Ari sorry update it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of gratitude for Chuck for investing the time and making me learn a lot. But the issue I had was more for a stupid reason that anything else. Having multiple catkin workspaces, I tend to source the terminal if and when required. While running ROS, I run the code above using a new terminal. I just did not source it and hence I couldn't locate the packages (and consequently services) in that workspace despite the ROS running the nodes and services from those packages.

Comment: Well, glad you solved the problem problem, regardless of the cause. Sometimes even the trivial issues can cause endless headaches. Since you've solved your question, please accept it so future visitors can find the solution easier (accepted answers are always on top).

Answer (score 1):

What is the exact error you're getting? You have `random` in two locations - your module import (`from random.srv import *`), and when you setup the service proxy (`rospy.ServiceProxy('main/random_task', random)`.

An import error would probably mean Python can't find `random.srv`, where the service proxy error would probably mean that Python can't find `random.srv.random`, which means that it can't find the `random` service definition inside your `random.srv` file.

Maybe this is enough to point you in the right direction, but if not, could you *edit your question* to provide a link to the `random.srv` file?

---

**:EDIT:**

First, you need to get your naming straight. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8350853/5171120) on Stack Overflow, "How to import module when module name has a '-' dash or hyphen in it?" The two top answers are, in short:

> [you can't. `foo-bar` is not an identifier. rename the file to `foo_bar.py`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8350881/5171120)

And

> [If you can't rename the module to match Python naming conventions, create a new module to act as an intermediary:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8350938/5171120)
>
> ```
>  ---- foo_proxy.py ----
>  tmp = __import__('foo-bar')
>  globals().update(vars(tmp))
>
>  ---- main.py ----
>  from foo_proxy import *
> ```

Second, you might have a naming conflict with `main/srv`. Check out the [tutorial on creating messages and services](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv). Specifically, I noticed:

> Also you need the same changes to package.xml for services as for messages, so look above for the additional dependencies required.
>
> Remove # to uncomment the following lines:
>
> ```
> # add_service_files(
> #   FILES
> #   Service1.srv
> #   Service2.srv
> # )
> ```

It would seem to me that, if you already had a `main.srv` declared in your `package.xml` file, then it might be chance that your services are getting read, because your `my-package1` folder happens to be in the `src` folder (so it's on the path) and then `main.srv` shares a name with something else. Sharing names is bad, especially when you're importing all, because of the same reason [`import *`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2386714/5171120) or [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/5171120) is bad - you can/might/will overwrite something and then it's not clear which function/service/method you're actually using.

My suggestions would be:

1. Rename your `my-package1` to `my_package1`.
2. Put all of the services for `my_package1` in the `my_package1\srv` folder - don't use `\main\` as a subfolder if possible.

Try these, see if it helps. If it does, and you have a *related* question, please start a new question and link to this one if you feel it provides context for the new question. If this isn't the answer you're looking for, please *edit your question* to reflect what happened when you tried the steps above.

Comment: I made the changes to make it more info

Comment: @Zero - I'll try my best to update the answer here, but in the future please *start a new question* if you have a new question. In the future, if a question is solved, please accept the answer to mark it as solved and ask a new one. You can reference earlier questions whenever you make a new question; just click the "share" button under the post to get a link and then put that link in your new question.